# Add Items to Document Tree That is Sitting in Web Part

Tags: 2010, web-part

I've inherited a very confusing SharePoint intranet that keeps giving me hell. There's a web part on each page that contains a document tree. Each page has different documents in the tree. Based on this, I figured there must be some data source populating each web part based on the page it is placed on. But for the life of me, I can't figure out where the data source is coming from. I've checked the document library (nothing found), checked the lists with some promise. There is an over-arching list, but I can only see/edit each View (each view represents each page the web part is placed on), which only allows me to edit the columns and list settings.

Still haven't found where the list items (documents in the tree) are being populated from...

Has anyone ever dealt with a document tree in a web part on multiple pages? I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably export the web part and see the details. If it's a content query web part value of the List name shows the data source.

Ex: `<property name="ListName" type="string">Documents</property>`

Also you can see web part name and assembly details in the exported file. If it's a custom web part get the assembly details and use a decompiler to analyse the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the List Name property is a GUID. And I don't see any dll referenced to decompile.

Comment: You can use power shell to get the list details from the ID                          Get-SPSite http://sp2010 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq “LIST-ID-GOES-HERE”} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder